# How to change line color based on data range in r plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create a plotly line graph which can change its color based on the value threshold. I am unable to find the option in r plotly. Below is the code:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(mdata1, x = ~TTIME, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',  color= list(~ENTITY_NAME,fill.color= ()) , fill = 'tozeroy') %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Date',showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(title = 'Memory Percentage'))
```

[image]

Comment: Please `dput()` your data to make your example reproducible. Also please remember to include all library statements in your code.

Comment: Please find the libraries for the app                                                          library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ROracle)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)
library(DT).

Comment: Also please find the data pulled from a database query:TTIME      ENTITY_NAME variable  value
1  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 30.718
2  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 30.854
3  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 31.262
4  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 32.538
5  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 32.569
6  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 32.614
7  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 32.627
8  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE  32.71
9  17-NOV-2016 05   lrtp30.fmr.com    VALUE 32.743